# How to protect data in Documents directory with encryption?

Tags: ios, swift, security, encryption

I have an app that downloads several pdfs and images and save them in the `Documents` directory. I need these files to be protected by everyone who try to access them via tools like iExplorer. I found the iOS Security Guide and I enabled the `Data Protection` capability. I then tried to create a txt file in this way :

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
let filePath = documentsPath + "/hello.txt"

FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: Data.init(base64Encoded: "HELLOOOOOOOO"), attributes: [kCFURLFileProtectionKey as String: FileProtectionType.complete])
```

Then, I tried to use iExplorer to access the txt file and I was able to do it as for any other non protected file. I did having my iPhone unlocked and also locked and after wait up to 5 minutes. The files were there accessible without any problem. I really need to know if there's a way to make them unaccessible, at least when device is locked.

Another solution I was thinking about is to encrypt the files in the Documents folder with a custom algorithm, but in this way in case of big files we lose the speed in opening the file because everytime we need to decrypt it and this requires an amount of time that depends on the size of the file itself.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a file that is inaccessible when unlocked, you have to write the following:

```
let filePath = "path/to/place"
let bar = "HII"
let fileAttr = [NSFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionComplete]
fileManager.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: bar, attributes: fileAttr)
```

It is still accessible when unlocked though. If the people really want to find the files, they will try tons of ways to access it though.

Note: This code is not tested

If you want to have complete protection, you can encrypt with AES and then decrypt when it is needed to be read, but it will lead to a loss of performance

Comment: I am creating one folder inside the document directory and then storing the files. So I added `fileAttr` attribute while creating a new directory. But still, while I navigate to that folder I can access those documents.

`let fileAttr = [FileAttributeKey.protectionKey : FileProtectionType.complete]

try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dirPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: fileAttr)`